# Existence and unicity of a constant $c$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi} \frac {x + c}{\sin x}$ is finite

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

Supposing $c = - \pi$. Then, the quotient will assume the form $0/0$. Using L'Hospital

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \pi} \dfrac {x-\pi}{\sin x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \pi} \dfrac {1}{\cos x} = -1$$

So, for $c= - \pi$, $ \dfrac {x + c}{\sin x}$ tends to a finite limit when x $ \rightarrow \pi$.

What argument could I use **to prove** that **that's the only value for c** such that **the limit is finite?**

Comment: If $c$ is not $-\pi$, then the numerator goes to a non-zero constant but the denominator goes to $0$ which means you can not get a finite limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x \to \pi$, you may write $x=\pi-\epsilon$ with $\epsilon \to 0$ and using the Taylor expansion for $\epsilon$ near $0$, you have
$$
\sin x =\sin (\pi-\epsilon)= \epsilon+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)
$$ you obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\frac {x + c}{\sin x}&=\frac {\pi-\epsilon+c}{\sin (\pi - \epsilon)}\\\\
&=\frac {\pi+c-\epsilon}{\epsilon+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)}\\\\
&=\frac {\pi+c}{\epsilon}-1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)\\\\
\end{align}
$$ and the latter expression, as $\epsilon \to 0$, is finite if and only  if $\pi+c=0$, as announced.